# How to invoke a axis2 web service project added as jar dependency to another Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, apache-axis, web.xml

I created `Axis2` web service as a maven project `ProjectB` and packaged it as jar.I added this `ProjectB` jar as dependency to the another maven project which is `ProjectA` in pom.xml.

jar file of my `ProjectB` added as dependency to `ProjectA`  `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>Axis2WebService</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In web services jar which I added to another project doesn't contain `Webcontent` folder. So, my concern would be

1. How to invoke my webservice which is inside jar in the `ProjectA`?
2. Do I need to add anything in my `web.xml` of `ProjectA` in order to find my webservice?
3. How can I access my webservice in the browser(i.e. `http://localserver:port/ProjectA/Myservice`). Is this the right way to access my webservice?
4. Do I need to again specify all axis2 dependent jars in `projectA`pom.xml or Axis 2 servlets mappings in `ProjectA` web.xml?

I am struck on this for a day.Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're calling your Web Service projectB, and your Web Service Client projectA. If that's the case, then you have a little confusion there. You need to deploy your Web Service (projectB) in an application server (i.e as a war in a tomcat server or ear in jboss or weblogic, etc). Then, you need to generate your client stubs with "Maven2 WSDL2Code Plug-in" and use that client as dependency in your projectA. This proyectA will use the stubs in the generated dependency to access your Web Service. Sorry that I can't format this answer, I'm begind a proxy that blocks all java script (I can't even post comments)...

Comment: @donsenior.....`ProjectA` is the not he webservice client.It's our main webapp project which consists all the functionality of our Project.`ProjectB` is Webservice which entirely independent of `ProjectA`.I just want to deploy `ProjectB` as a Jar file inside the `ProjectA` library.So, I got a question what should mention in `web.xm` in order to invoke webservice as the service resides in the jar file.

Comment: Why would you do that? If the WS is independent why don't you just deploy it in the same app server where your webapp is?